# How to stop search bar from scroling with tableheader for iPhone

Tags: iphone

I want to make my search bar static but not scrolling with `tableview`. I did this:

`self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;`

but I want to make my search bar just static. I have a `UItableViewController`. How to make it static?

Comment: plz help is it necessary to have only view based app to stop serach bar moving up ??

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `UISearchBar` to the main view. Use IB to do this, or use

```
[self.view addSubview:searchBar];
```

if you are creating them programmatically. Either way, also make sure the `UITableView` is positioned some 40px lower.